# VPNs and NetBIOS

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec

NetBIOS can't be passed through VPNs at all correct? And you have to run a DNS or WINS server for name lookups and network discovery to work correct? Or does it depend on the VPN type.

I've been doing some reading and I am trying to wrap my head around how Windows Machines see each other over networks whether its site-to-site or client-to-site.

The VPN operates on the same local network 192.168.50.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you have a very small network you have to run WINS anyway as NETBUI (the non IP NetBIOS is a L2 protocol only. You could extend this over a VPN by using (SRB) source route bridging (it puts the L2 protocol in a special tunnel) and then run it over a VPN. Or if you build your VPN by encrypting a GRE tunnel (DMVPN) does this, or use an GRE tunnel and IPSEC transport mode that will also work, based on your statement that the network is the same subnet GRE with IPSEC transport mode will work.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the VPN type, or more accurately the layer that the VPN operates at, and for NetBIOS how the networking is configured since NetBIOS doesn't cross broadcast domains.

Comment: What VPN types would allow NetBIOS to pass through?